# pyspark list, find the item that appears the most

Tags: list, pyspark, frequency

I need to find the item that appears the most in a pyspark list.
suppose I have a list like:

```
mylist = [a, b, c, s, c, c, s, a, c]
```

I need to know that c is the one that has the highest frequency.

I searched some similar answers and I tried

```
from collections import Counter
```

but cannot import name counter. Does this have to with pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this list small enough (roughly < 100k elements) that you can do this in base Python? If so, then you don't even need Spark.

```py
from collections import Counter
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 's', 'c', 'c', 's', 'a', 'c']
counter = Counter(mylist)
print(counter.most_common()[:5]) # get the five most common elements
```

If you have a fairly big file of elements to count, then you may want to use Spark. In this case, you wouldn't even need `collections`. Check out the [Spark examples page](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html) for some sample code.

As to why you can't import `Counter`, I'm not sure, especially since `collections` is a package provided by default. Try opening up a regular Python shell and running `import collections`, `collections.Counter`. I ran the exact same import line you gave and it worked for me.